# How to average 2D array columns based on date header

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on some glaicer borehole temperature data consisting of ~1,000 rows by 700 columns. The vertical index is depth (i.e. as you move down the array depth increases) and the column headers are datetime values (i.e. as you move right along the array you move forwards in time).

I am looking for a way to average all temperatures in the columns depending on a date sampling rate. For example, the early datetimes have a spacing of 10 minutes, but the later datetimes have a spacing of six hours.

It would be good to be able to put in the sampling as an input and get out data based on that sampling rate so that I can see which one works best.

It would also be good that if I choose say 3 hour sampling this is simply ignored for spacing of above 3 hours and no change to the data is made in this case (i.e. datetime spacings of 10 minutes are averaged, but datetime spacings of 6 hours are left unaffected).

All of this needs to come out in either a pandas dataframe with date as column headers and depth as the index, or as a numpy array and separate list of datetimes.

I'm fairly new to Python, and this is my first question on stackoverflow!! Thanks :)

(I know the following is not totally correct use of Pandas, but it works for the figure slider I've produced!)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#example array
T = np.array([  [-2, -2, -2, -2.1, -2.3, -2.6],
                [-2.2, -2.3, -3, -3.1, -3.3, -3.3],
                [-4, -4, -4.5, -4.4, -4.6, -4.5]])

#example headers at 8 and then 4 hour spacing
headers = [pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24 00:00:00', end='2018-04-24 08:00:00', periods=3).tolist() +
            pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24 12:00:00', end='2018-04-25 12:00:00', periods=3).tolist()]

#pandas dataframe in same setup as much larger one I'm using
T_df = pd.DataFrame(T, columns = headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is to convert your time series to a numeric series, and then use the groupby method.

For instance, imagine you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['10:00:00', 1.],['10:10:00', 2.],['10:20:00', 3.],['10:30:00', 4.]],columns=['Time', 'Value'])
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%X')
```

You can convert your time series by:

```
df['DeltaT'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time).dt.total_seconds().astype(int) 
df['DeltaT'] -= df['DeltaT'][0] # To start to 0
```

Then use the groupby method. You can for instance create a new column to floor the time interval you want:

```
myInterval = 1200.
df['group'] = (df['DeltaT']/myInterval).astype(int)
```

So you can use groupby followed by mean() (or a function you define)

```
df.groupby('group').mean()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the tips! My pandas array is set up slightly differently, but I am trying to use the detla time aspect of this answer

Comment: Happy that I could help! Do not hesitate to browse the groupby pandas doc as it contains lots of useful applications